# ReferenceError: twttr is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

The following social media calls works exactly as it should for Chome and Safari, but Facebook and Twitter fail to load under Firefox and logs the message "twitter is not defined" in the console.
Would anyone have any idea about how to correct that?

HTML calls:

```
<script id="twitter-wjs" async type="text/javascript" async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer src="custom.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.streacher').addClass('activeScale');

    twttr.ready(function (event) {
        var containersWidth = $('.titleContentNews').width();

        $('div.instaDiv').css({ 'height': containersHeigh + 'px' });
        $('#facebookDiv').append('<iframe src="URL" width="' + containersWidth + '" height="' + containersHeigh + '"  style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');
        $('.twitter-timeline').css({ 'height': containersHeigh + 'px' });
        $('.instaScroller').css({ 'height': containersHeigh + 'px' });
    });
});
```

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the twitter `script` tag is `async`, it may not have been loaded prior to the document's `onLoad` event (which is when you invoke `twttr`). The easiest (if not very performant) solution is just to remove the `async` attribute from the `script` tag. This [article](https://css-tricks.com/async-attribute-scripts-bottom/) has more detailed explanations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Huy, that seems to have fixed it.
I had also somehow not realised (even though that didn't seem to impact on the result) that I had used async twice!!
In any case, removing it seems to have fixed the issue, so a massive thank you for taking your time to help out, really.
I'm sorry I cannot upvote your answer due to my beginner's level apparently, but thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer states, the issue is the `async` attribute of the `twitter-wjs` script.

To keep the async attribute, you can initialize the twttr object like so:

```
var twttr = twttr || {};
```

which creates an empty object to which you can attach the ready function until the script loads.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacob. Removing the async did indeed resolve the problem. The odd thing is that I had removed it once to try but it didn't work then, which is when I realised that just like the code above, I had typed it twice and removing one simply made no difference as the second was still there.
In any case, all seems fine now so a massive thank you to you for taking your time to help out, I really appreciate it.